# Abrir pantalla al dar click en input y que retorne datos escritos

Tags: javascript

Necesito que al dar un click en un input tipo text me aparezca una pantalla donde pueda ingresar texto y que al presionar un botón de "Aceptar" me regrese los datos escritos y los ponga en el input original.

Por ejemplo:

- `Input1` cuando se le ejecute el evento `click` que se abra un modal.

El modal tiene un `input2` donde el usuario puede escribir (estados de México por ejemplo) y con un botón "Aceptar" cerrar esta pantalla y que los estados escritos en el `input2` se escriban en el `input1`.

Comment: Debes mostrar el código que has intentado hacer o que tengas, errores etc para poderte ayudar, **Es importante que leas [ask]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que necesitas puedes usar esta libreria [alertifyjs](http://alertifyjs.com/) espero te ayude saludos.

al hacer `click` ejecutamos el `prompt` y después al darle aceptar agregamos el valor con `$("#input1").val(value)`

```js
$("#input1").click(function(){
 alertify.prompt( 'Prompt Title', 'Prompt Message', 'Prompt Value'
               , function(evt, value) { 
               alertify.success('You entered: ' + value) 
               $("#input1").val(value) 
               }
               , function() { 
               alertify.error('Cancel') 
               });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>
<input id="input1" type="text" name="" value="">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba y me sirvió!

Comment: Excelente amigo que bueno ayudarte saludos